# JavaScript and Laravel php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

I am developing a product form where the user has the option to create several input fields.
When I click the button to create a new input, JavaScript return me the new field. But within the JavaScript contains the PHP tags "laravel" and as it turns template code is within double quotes and my code does not work.

JavaScript code:

```
//FUNÇÕES PARA PAGINA DE PRODUTOS
$(function(){

//CRIANDO CAMPOS DINAMICAMENTE
var scntDiv = $('#campos_roupas');
var i       = $('#campos_roupas').size() + 1;

$('#mais_roupa').live('click', function() {
    $('<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Número:<span class="required">*</span></label><div class="col-md-2">{{ Form::select("categoria_pai", Variaveis::where("categoria", "=", 1 )->lists("variavel", "id"), "", array("class" => "form-control")) }}</div><label class="col-md-1 control-label">Cor:<span class="required">*</span></label><div class="col-md-2">{{ Form::select("categoria_pai", Variaveis::where("categoria", "=", 2 )->lists("variavel", "id"), "", array("class" => "form-control")) }}</div><label class="col-md-2 control-label">Estoque:<span class="required">*</span></label><div class="col-md-2">{{ Form::text("estoque", Input::old("estoque"), array("class" => "form-control")) }}</div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
});
});
```

Could inform me as sending it to the PHP without the quotes at the beginning and end?

Comment: Is the code you posted part of a Laravel php blade template file or is it part of a javascript file?

Comment: Is part of javascript. But this code insert inside php blade

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code you get after the page is rendered and `{{ Form::select... }} has generated the html select. Also what's the js error you get in your browser's console?

Comment: After JavaScript rendered the code show this in html:

<div class="col-md-2">
    "{{ Form::select("categoria_pai", Variaveis::where("categoria", "=", 1 )-&gt;lists("variavel", "id"), "", array("class" =&gt; "form-control")) }}"
</div>

You can see the quotes at begin and end like a string and not a php code

Comment: Just to be clear: the code you posted is part of `somefile.js` and you include that inside the blade file with `<script src="somefile.js"></script>`?

Comment: I have a file somefile.js and a file.blade.php.
In file.blade.php file has a button that calls the function in somefile.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have blade code in external js file, because that is executed on the client side in the browser and the blade code between `{{ ... }}` is php and can only be executed on the server. So to mix Blade and Javascript code, you need to embed the JavaScript inside `file.blade.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//FUNÇÕES PARA PAGINA DE PRODUTOS
$(function(){

//CRIANDO CAMPOS DINAMICAMENTE
var scntDiv = $('#campos_roupas');
var i       = $('#campos_roupas').size() + 1;

$('#mais_roupa').live('click', function() {
    $('<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Número:<span class="required">*</span></label><div class="col-md-2">{{ Form::select("categoria_pai", Variaveis::where("categoria", "=", 1 )->lists("variavel", "id"), "", array("class" => "form-control")) }}</div><label class="col-md-1 control-label">Cor:<span class="required">*</span></label><div class="col-md-2">{{ Form::select("categoria_pai", Variaveis::where("categoria", "=", 2 )->lists("variavel", "id"), "", array("class" => "form-control")) }}</div><label class="col-md-2 control-label">Estoque:<span class="required">*</span></label><div class="col-md-2">{{ Form::text("estoque", Input::old("estoque"), array("class" => "form-control")) }}</div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
});
});

</script>
```

You can't include it from an external file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help it worked.
I did not know that the code had to be on the same page.